# Is there way to avoid password being explicitly provided in Trino CLI

Tags: trino

I am currently trying to connect Trino using Java CLI,

option-1: works fine, here password is explicitly mentioned every time,

```
export TRINO_PASSWORD=abcd
export TRINO_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD=efgh
java -jar -Duser.timezone=UTC trino-cli-407-executable.jar
--server https://xxx:443 
--keystore-path keystore.jks 
--keystore-password $TRINO_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD 
--catalog <catalogname> 
--user <username> 
--password
```

option-2: did not work

```
java -jar -Duser.timezone=UTC trino-cli-407-executable.jar
--server https://xxx:443 
--keystore-path keystore.jks
--keystore-password /path/keystore_password 
--catalog <catalogname> 
--user <username> 
--password /path/password
```

If i provide the password through the filename, it does not work.

I want to know how we can achieve by avoiding the password to be explicitly provided in the JAVA CLI. Is there a way to provide password through file path and then mask the password.

TIA.